OpenSSHサーバーのchrootの設定方法について
環境
Linuxサーバー(Sambaで共有ファオルダ開放済み)と『Windows10＋Linux』のクライアント
※1 『LinuxサーバーとWindowsクライアント』のやり取りを、原則、想定しています
サーバー側のユーザー名= boo

※2 サーバーはSambaで共有フォルダ下記が開放されています
LinuxサーバーとLinuxクライアントはsmbClient＋Pythonでファイル転送しています
/home/boo/share

※3 OpenSSHサーバー内ではファイル転送に加え、
「フォルダ名やファイル名の取得」や「ファイル内容の書換え」等がしたいです
※4 SSHの処理はParamiko＋Pythonで行うことを想定しています
※5 OpenSSHへのアクセスは『パスワード認証方式』です
上記(※1から5)の条件のもとで下記に記載した方法で正しいのか、
下段記載の質問に対してアドバイスを頂きたいのです。宜しくお願いします
要望
Sambaと同じ'/home/boo/share'以下の階層のみSSHでディレクトリを開放したい
# 下記の記述は私がネットで調べた情報を寄せ集めて自分なりにまとめたのですが正しいかどうか判断がつきません
①SSHとは ・・それ自身で存在し、コマンドライン・ログイン・遠隔コマンド実行ができる
②SFTPとは・・SSH上に存在し、ファイルアクセス・転送・管理機能を提供するプロトコル
※ 上記①②の掲載は私がネット情報から引用し、この前提で下記質問をしています。
※ もし、①②が間違った認識ならご指摘下さい。
＜手順１＞  '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'を開き下記を追記する
        # chrootする記述
        Match User boo
        ChrootDirectory /home/boo/share
        # ForceCommand internal-sftp [オプション]   ←  該当ユーザーは  SSHを無効化しSFTPを強制する

＜手順2＞
$ sudo service ssh restart（sshdの再起動）
＜手順3＞
$ sudo chown root:root                  ←  （ユーザー：グループ）ディレクトリ内の全てファイルの所有権を変更する
$ sudo chmod 755 /home/boo/share        ←  オーナーに「読取り権限」「書込み権限」「実行権限」を渡し
その他のユーザーには「読取り権限」「実行権限」のみ
        ※ chmod 777 とは、すべてのユーザーに「読取り権限」「書込み権限」「実行権限」を渡す

        [注意点] ネット情報だと'chroot'の設定は、『root:root で 755』でなければならない仕様だそうです

質問
質問①  パスワード認証方式でもchrootは設定できますか？
質問②  ChrootDirectory /home/boo/shareのパスの指定方法は正しいですか？
質問③  ForceCommand internal-sftp [オプション] はコメントアウトのままでOKですか？
   私のSSHの認識はそれ自身で存在し、コマンドライン・ログイン・遠隔コマンド実行ができる
   また、SFTPの認識はSSH上に存在し、ファイルアクセス・転送・管理機能を提供するプロトコル
   なので

   'ForceCommand internal-sftp [オプション]' を設定すると「SSHを無効化しSFTPを強制される」
   と考えました。私の希望は下記、※3ですので

   >※3 OpenSSHサーバー内ではファイル転送に加え、「フォルダ名やファイル名の取得」や「ファイル内容の書換え」等・・・
   
   コメントアウトしておいた方が良いのか迷ってますし、
   また、'ForceCommand internal-sftp'はChrootを設定する上で、「必須条件」なのか、解りません

質問④  'root:root'の意味がわかりません。これを設定すると
'$ ssh root@192.168.x.xx'でないとログインできないのでは？
'$ ssh boo@192.168.x.xx'（一般ユーザー）ではログインできないのでしょいうか？
質問⑤  上記④に類似してますが、'chmod 755'にすると
'$ ssh boo@192.168.x.xx'（一般ユーザー）では操作はできますか？
質問⑥  [注意点]  の内容は正しいことなのですか？

問題を切り分ける必要がありそうです。ssh越しでない、単純なchroot環境の構築方法は分かっていますか？ わからないならまずは質問文からsshを外すべきです。分かっているなら、どこがわからないのかを尋ねてください。

sayuri様、コメントありがとう御座います。sshとchrootは別物なのでしょうか?（sshがchrootを内包していると思ってました）sshもつい先日、設定出来たばかりで何も分かっていません。「どこがわからない・・・」では、私が混乱しています。１、私の質問は上記の設定方法が正しのか否か、及び、２、仮に設定方法がOKだったとしても「上記質問①〜⑤の理解が私自身出来ていないので、どなたかの教えて欲しいのです。」とい意味で掲載しました。ネット記述で集めた情報だけなので、初めての私には全体像がまだ見えていません。宜しくご指導お願いします

追伸、sayuri様、上記コメントで「sshを外すべき」とアドバイスを頂きましたが、sshの説明を外しても、その他の方が閲覧して頂く際に私の真意が伝わるのでしょうか?私の希望は最終的に「paramiko＋pythonでファイル転送やファイル内容の変更をすること」が前提なので、より詳細な環境や状況を明示していたのです。一部だけ切り取って質問して、うまく行ったとしてもコードを書く段階で間違いに気づき、再設定するより、情報をオープンして解決したいと考えたのです。「それでも今回の件ではsshについては削除した方が良い」と言うご提案なら削除しますね。私自身どこまでを情報開示すべきか、質問サイトをあまり利用しなかったので分かりません。他の質問サイトでは情報が少ないと、かなり指摘されます。そのあたりも含め、ご指導お願いします。

再追伸、sayuri様、ひょっとして「①SSHとは 」「②SFTPとは」の件の削除を示唆していたのでしょうか?だとしたらコメントの趣旨が理解できました。納得です。なぜ、掲載したかと言うと、当然、sayuri様のようなITエンジニアの方は当然、ご周知だと思います。これは、私がネット情報から引用した内容で、これを前提で質問しています。と明示しています。もし、この「①SSHとは 」「②SFTPとは」が間違った認識なら要領を得ない質問ばかりになってしまいます。ただ、もう少し、丁寧な物書きをすれば良かったと、反省しています。自分の頭では理解してるので、第三者が読むことに配慮がありませんでした。以後、気おつけます。今後とも、きたんのないご意見、宜しくお願いします

解決したからといって 質問を編集して情報を削除しないでください。 質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保つべきで、"編集" も間違いを修正したり不足している情報を追記するなど一定のルールがあります。 / 感謝の気持ちも同様に、質問に追記するのではなくコメント欄を使用してください。

cubbick様、ご連絡ありがとうございます。ご指摘の件、了解しました。今、タブレットで閲覧していますので、明日、pcから修正しておきます。

アドバイスくださった皆様、本当にありがとうございます
残りの質問は、設定を進めながら判断し、もし問題が発生するようなら
再度、当サイトで質問させて頂きます。その節は宜しくお願いします

全部は読んでいないのですが、大事な認識が欠けているようなのでそこだけ指摘しておきます。
質問者さんの要求は、sshでログインしたユーザが、システム全体にアクセスできないようにしたいということで、そのためにchrootの仕組みを利用することを検討しているというとですよね。
それはありなのですが、chrootというのは書いてあるとおりrootディレクトリを変更するという操作なので、変更先のディレクトリにはそのための準備が必要になるということに注意が必要です。
たとえば、実行ファイルは/usr/binなどに置かれていますが、これはrootディレクトリ配下にありまので、変更先のrootディレクトリにも用意しておく必要があります。動作に必要なライブラリなど他にも必要なものがあります。
コメントで「単純なchroot環境の構築方法は分かっていますか？」とあるのはそのことを指摘しているのだと思います。
たとえば、以下の記事が参考になるでしょう。
https://tech.kurojica.com/archives/32888/

そのような面倒のことをせずにアクセス先だけ変更したいという場合、sftpのみの接続を受け付けるようにするという手があります。sftpは一部のファイル操作ができ、また、他のライブラリを必要としないので、面倒な環境構築は不要になります。

YTAKAI様、コメント頂きありがとうございます。ご指摘の件、納得いたしまた。まだ、chrootの設定をしておりませんでしたので、助かりました。このような有益な情報が無かったら、知らずに設定をして「大きなトラブル」になっていたと思います。私は現在、python＋paramiko(scp)でsftpの転送等の試験をしていますが、自分の希望どうりの動作が確認出来ているので、chrootに固執しないでおきます。私はまだ、知識(経験)も浅く、間違えた認識で行動しがちです。時より、このサイトに質問をしに来ますので、今後とも宜しくお願い致します。p.s.添付して頂いたURLは確認しておきます。ありがとうございます


質問⑥　[注意点]　の内容は正しいことなのですか？

数年前に似たようなことをしました(ForceCommand internal-sftpにしたサーバを立てました)が、そうでしたね。

質問⑤　上記④に類似してますが、'chmod 755'にすると
'$ ssh boo@192.168.x.xx'（一般ユーザー）では操作はできますか？

一次情報は
man sshd_config

でしょう。ここで ChrootDirectory を確認すると

At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.

と書いてありますから、ChrootDirectory で指定したディレクトリとそれより上はすべて、root がオーナーで他のユーザ/グループの書き込みが不可である必要がある、と読めます。
他のユーザ/グループの書き込みが不可、はつまりchmod 755ですね。
ChrootDirectory に指定したディレクリが一般ユーザに書き換えられるようにはするな、という話です。
一般ユーザが触れるディレクトリは その下 に作らないといけなかったです。


質問④　'root:root'の意味がわかりません。これを設定すると
'$ ssh root@192.168.x.xx'でないとログインできないのでは？
'$ ssh boo@192.168.x.xx'（一般ユーザー）ではログインできないのでしょいうか？

Linuxのファイルシステムを考えてみてください。
ルートディレクトリ(/)は、 root がオーナーで、一般ユーザは書き込み不可つまりルートディレクトリの操作ができないのは とても当たり前 ですよね?
ルートディレクトリより下のディレクトリのいずれかが一般ユーザでも読み書き可能で、そのような読み書き可能なディレクトリの どこか がそのユーザのホームディレクトリになっていて、それで一般ユーザはログインできますよね?
とりあえず分かるところだけ書きました。

ここから下はなんとなくの想像ですが、
/opt/sshd_onother_root とか作ってChrootDirectoryに指定
/opt/sshd_onother_root/homeもroot権限で作成
/opt/sshd_onother_root/home/booを、/home/booのシンボリックリンクかなにかで作る
みたいな感じになるんじゃないでしょうか。それで(期待通り)動くかは分かりませんけれども。

quickquip様、大変貴重でピンポイントなアドバイスありがとうございます。とても符に落ちて目の前の霧が晴れました。

quickquip様、本当にありがとうございます
残りの質問は、設定を進めながら判断し、もし問題が発生するようなら
再度、当サイトで質問させて頂きます。その節は宜しくお願いします
